# Angular2 + Firebase - Uploading Images - [ts] Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. any

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm following along with a Firebase video on how to upload images.

**The issue**

I believe the tutorials JavaScript is written inside a script tag within a HTML document.

I'm using Angular and I think TypeScript is being a little stricter on some of the syntax and I'm not entirely sure on how to get around it.

**Question**

How do I get around this : 'Uploader.value' throws the following error ?

> [ts] Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Below is my code so far:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects-add',
  templateUrl: './photos-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photos-add.component.css']
})

export class PhotosAddComponent implements OnInit {

  projectDetails: FormGroup;
  currentRoute: string = this.router.url;
  userId;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { 
     this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid;
      } else {
        console.log('not signed in');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Get Upload Elements
    var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader'); 
    // var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

    var fileButton = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('fileButton'));

    // Listen for file selection
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

      // Get File
      var file = (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files[0];

      // Create a storage Ref
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('photos/' + file.name);

      // Upload File
      var task = storageRef.put(file);

      // Upload Progress Bar
      task.on('state_changed',

      function progress(snapshot) {
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          uploader.value = percentage;
          console.log('uploader value is = ' + uploader);
          console.log('file name is = ' + file.name);
      },

      function error(err) {

      },

      function complete() {
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Any assistance here would be massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular way of doing it would be

**HTML** :

add `#uploader` to your element tag;

**Typescript:**

instead of

```
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
```

do this:

```
  @ViewChild('uploader') private uploader;
```

After that you can use it as:

```
  this.updatedTask.nativeElement.value=percentage; ..etc
```